# Jekyll Blog Searching

Tags: ruby, plugins, blogs, jekyll

I have to Implement a substring search feature on my blog site.  currently i have static search feature on my blog
for example : 
Content:  "Naushad is Here"
Search for : "shad"
            For the above content, if you search for 'shad' you won't get any results. 
            So we need you to implement a substring static search.

So is there any plugin that I can use. and the last thing I can develop an algorithm in Java but I am new in ruby and Jekyll so I want to know how can I implement this feature in my Blog.
So please help me out as soon as possible. 
Thank you so much for consideration in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at Pascal Widdershoven's search plugin https://github.com/PascalW/jekyll_indextank it's quite old but it can be a good starting point.